# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jxl/JXLException

Tags: jakarta-ee, jxl, wsad5.1, jboss-3.x

what's up?!
First I'd like you to consider the follow:

- I have an application running with Java 1.4, J2EE 1.3;
- Jboss 3.2.7;
- IDE is WSAD;
- iReport and jasperreports, version 3.7.1;

The development environment is set up in Windows XP, running in an Oracle VM. I have tried at least I think every possible configuration to make reports available in .xls format. I've already tried to set up jxl-2.6.jar in the build path of EJB project and Web project, I opened the ear to see the jars added and jxl-2.6.jar is there but every time I try to export the report to .xls format it returns java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jxl/JXLException and now I have no clue of what could be possibly happening so that's my question, if someone could help, in advance I'm so very thankful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how are you?

I got to solve this problem, I just had to add jxl-2.6.jar as a Java JAR Dependency in my EJB project in WSAD I did the follow:

I added the jxl-2.6.jar in the EJB build path and right clicked in EJB project -> Properties -> Java JAR Dependency then I flagged the jxl-2.6.jar and clicked in apply button and then OK.

tks